# Reversing words in place

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ex. Input: `rat the ate cat the`

Output: `the cat ate the rat`

Here's my code so far:

```
def reverse_message(starting, ending, msg):

    while(starting < ending):
        msg[starting], msg[ending] = msg[ending], msg[starting]
        starting += 1 
        ending -= 1

def reverse_words(msg):

    # Decode the message by reversing the words
    # reverse entire message
    reverse_message(0, len(msg) - 1, msg)

    #reverse each word
    starting = 0
    for i in range(len(msg)):
        if ((msg[i] == ' ') or (i == len(msg) - 1)):
            reverse_message(starting, i-1, msg)
            starting = i+1
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: First, explain _why_ do you think you are doing something wrong. For starters, what is `msg`? If it is a string, then it is immutable.

Comment: Why are you reversing each word?

Comment: Because after you reverse the entire message it will turn out to be: 

eht tac eta eht tar

Then you would want to reverse each word to get the output

Comment: @koreannnnnnn Words will not be reversed. The order of words in the sentence will be reversed.

Comment: I tried to do it without split and reverse, check if the answer helps you! @koreannnnnnn

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in a single line:
`str=' '.join(list(input().split(' '))[::-1])`

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, I would avoid explicitly passing a starting and ending index, instead relying on the message itself, where starting index is the first, and the ending index is the last index of the string, also I will pass the string as a list, since strings are mutable and cannot be changed, but list can.

```
def reverse_word(msg):

    starting = 0
    ending = len(msg)-1
    while(starting < ending):
        tmp = msg[starting]
        msg[starting] = msg[ending]
        msg[ending] = tmp
        starting += 1 
        ending -= 1

    return msg
```

After that, to reverse the string, I will reverse the entire string first, and then reverse each word in the string in place, and then stitch the string back together for the output.

```
def reverse_message(msg):

    #Convert the string into list of characters
    chars = list(msg)
    #Reverse entire list
    chars = reverse_word(chars)
    starting = 0
    i = 0
    result = []
    #Iterate through the reversed list, and pick individual words based on 
    #whitespace, and then reverse them in place
    while i < len(chars):
        if chars[i] == ' ':
            #Append all reversed words to another list
            result += reverse_word(chars[starting:i]) + [' ']
            starting = i+1
        i+=1
    #Reverse the last remaining word
    result += reverse_word(chars[starting:i])
    #Stitch the list back to string and return it
    return ''.join(result)
```

The resultant output will look like.

```
print(reverse_message('rat the ate cat the'))
#the cat ate the rat
```